# How to make auto refesh page stop working on Gridview Edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My auto refresh code in Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Auto refresh every 5 second
    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh",5+"; URL=Default.aspx");

    // Auto update into database
    con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conStr);

    GridView1.DataSourceID = "Datacmd";

    // Get status of process on server of pid(cells[6])
    count = GridView1.Rows.Count;
    string server = "";
    string pid = "";
    string status = "";
    string cout = GridView1.Rows.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        server = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;

        switch (server)
        {
            // If server locahost
            case "localhost":
                pid = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text;
                status = ws.GetStatusProcess(pid);   //Ws is My webservice have a function GetStatusProcess(string pid)
                string SQL = "UPDATE command SET status='" + status + "' WHERE id=" + int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text) + "";
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                GridView1.DataSourceID = "Datacmd";
                break;

            // case : etc...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Auto update into database is working fine.

However, when I click Button Edit on Gridview1 (ShowEditButton="True"), I can't Edit Rows on Gridview1. Because page will auto refresh.

How to make auto refresh page stop working on Gridview Edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using a session variable to store the state.
You could set the value in the RowEditing event of the gridview and reset it in the RowUpdated event and the RowCancelingEdit event.
In your Page_Load method you could use something like:

```
if (Session["myFlag"] == null)
{
    doStuff...
}
```

Comment: thanks. Howerver, I have a problem: when I click Edit event first time. Page so auto refesh, then it not auto refesh

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of header refresh use timer control. In your page_prerender event enable timer if gridview edit index>-1 else disable the timer. set you timer value to 5000 for 5 sec interval. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I've solved this by using Timer. It works like a charm
My code:

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conStr);

            //Auto refesh database
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "Datacmd";

            //Auto get status(cells[7]) of pid(cells[6])
            count = GridView1.Rows.Count;
            string server = "";
            string pid = "";
            string status = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                server = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                switch (server)
                {
                    //server locahost
                    case "localhost":
                        pid = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text;
                        status = ws.GetStatusProcess(pid);
                        string SQL = "UPDATE command SET status='" + status + "' WHERE id=" + int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text) + "";
                        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        GridView1.DataSourceID = "Datacmd";
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

[http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/359958/how-to-use-timer-in-asp-net][1]
```